# Type clash in Standard ML datatype with same constructor name

Tags: sml, ml

I need to describe in Standard-ML a language made of properties and values. My property system is made of properties which can have values, like for example:

```
color: red | yellow | blue | transparent
align: left | center | right
bgcolor: red | yellow | blue | transparent
```

I created this sml file which tries to describe these properties:

```
datatype colorvalue = Transparent
                    | Yellow
                    | Blue
                    | Red

datatype bgcolorvalue = Transparent
                      | Yellow
                      | Blue
                      | Red

datatype alignvalue = Left
                    | Center
                    | Right

(* Generic property: it can be any of the above *)
datatype property = Color of colorvalue
                  | BgColor of bgcolorvalue
                  | Align of alignvalue

(* Some values *)
val prop1: property = Color   Transparent
val prop2: property = BgColor Transparent
```

When I compile this in [MoscowML](http://mosml.org/) I get:

```
,File "c:\Users\myuser\documents\myproj\property.sml", line 21, characters 31-42:
! val prop1: property = Color   Transparent
!                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
! Type clash: expression of type
!   bgcolorvalue
! cannot have type
!   colorvalue
```

#### My guess

So I think that the problem is that `color` and `bgcolor` share a common property value: `transparent` which reflects in datatypes `colorvalue` and `bgcolorvalue` to share constructor `Transparent`. Actually they share all values, thus all constructors.

- Is it the reason for this failure?
- In any case, what should I do to describe my system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy to see that trying to use the same constructor in different types in the same scope would create problems with type inference. For example, what should the type of

```
fun heat Transparent = Yellow
|   heat Yellow = Red
|   heat Red = Blue
|   heat Blue = Blue;
```

be? `colorvalue ->colorvalue` or `bgbcolorvalue -> bgbcolorvalue` or `colorvalue -> bgbcolorvalue` or `bgbcolorvalue -> colorvalue`?

The easiest workaround would be to adopt different naming conventions for the constructors. You could also use structures (which is how SML keeps e.g. different uses of the name `map` in the basis library without any clashes). Something like:

```
structure Color = struct
    datatype value = Transparent
                   | Yellow
                   | Blue
                   | Red
end

structure BGBColor = struct
    datatype value = Transparent
                   | Yellow
                   | Blue
                   | Red
end;
```

Then you can do things like:

```
- val a = Color.Transparent;
val a = Transparent : Color.value

- val b = BGBColor.Transparent;
val b = Transparent : BGBColor.value
```

This last was run in the SML/NJ REPL and illustrates how there are now no clashes.

Comment: Thank you John, had a feeling that structures could help me. I am gonna try this and tell you! I have only one question. In the question I have omitted the fact that I have those datatypes enclosed in a big structure. Are there any problems if I nest structures?

Comment: @Andry Try it and see. I've never had occasion to do so, though I don't anticipate that there would be any problem.